# Добавления ограничений к button

Tags: javascript, functional-buttons

Пытаюсь добавить ограничения для кнопки. В моем случае при максимальном значении currentPeople (изначально 7) становится равным maxPeople (значение 12) кнопка становится не активной, но при уменьшении значения с помощью removeAttribute кнопка все равно не активна.
Так-же какое условие корректно будет прописать для кнопки отмены записи, что-бы оно не опускалось ниже изначального значения currentPeople (7)

```
<div>
      <p>Максимальное количество участников</p>
      <p class="lessonItem">${maxPeople}</p>
</div>
<div class="current-people-box">
      <p>Текущее количество участников</p>
      <p class="count-people">${currentPeople}</p>
</div>
<button class="sing-up">Записаться</button>
<button class="сancel-recording">Отменить запись</button>
```

```
let count = 1;

    const allBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.sing-up');
    allBtn.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const lessonItem = e.currentTarget.closest('.lesson-item');
            const countPeople = lessonItem.querySelector('.count-people', 'qqq');
            countPeople.innerHTML = +countPeople.innerHTML + count;

            const maxPeople = lessonItem.querySelector('.lessonItem');
            if (countPeople.innerHTML === maxPeople.innerHTML) {
                button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
            } else {
                button.removeAttribute('disabled');
            }

            
        })
    })

    const down = document.querySelectorAll('.сancel-recording');
    down.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const lessonItem = e.currentTarget.closest('.lesson-item');
            const countPeople = lessonItem.querySelector('.count-people');
            countPeople.innerHTML = +countPeople.innerHTML - count;

            const maxPeople = lessonItem.querySelector('.lessonItem');

        })
    })
```